# Jest Client instantiation based on cluster name /https URL/DNS name

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

Need to know if implementation of Jest client available for Https URL (not http- since it is available), or accessing Jest client only based on cluster name or based on DNS name.

suggest me if i am not aware of these implementations.

Issue opened on Git hub:  https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/issues/270

Edited:

Based on the below reference article , https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/jest/README.md 
it is clear Jest supports Https/SSL connections.

Just curious to know if it can support cluster name based configuration i.e without providing host or port details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Jest client version 0.1.4. Proxy and SSL configurations were not introduced in this version.

But with this following code, able to successfully access cluster URL without providing host and port details.

```
List<String> connectionUri = new ArrayList<String>();
connectionUri.add("https://search-testing.es.samplews.com");

jestFactory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig
.Builder(connectionUri)
.maxTotalConnection(maxTotalConnection)
.readTimeout(readTimeout)
.connTimeout(connTimeout)
.multiThreaded(true)
.build());
```

values:

```
maxTotalConnection = 50, readTimeout=60000, connTimeout=60000
```